# Make a 'Please wait' pop up window display in a WPF app

Tags: wpf, multithreading, popup

I want a pop up window to display while another form loads content from a service.
I can get this to happen but content disappears from the window if it runs more than once.
So I am trying to use Threads...

```
 private  Forms_Controls.BusyPopupWindow pop = new Forms_Controls.BusyPopupWindow();

  private void _ThreadPopupAnimation_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
      int x = 0;


      pop.Show();
  }

  private void _ThreadPopupAnimation_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                     RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {


  }
  private readonly BackgroundWorker _ThreadPopupAnimation = new BackgroundWorker();
  // Get the instance of the existing form.
  private void GrdViewCompletedForms_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
      _ThreadPopupAnimation.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_ThreadPopupAnimation_DoWork);
      _ThreadPopupAnimation.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_ThreadPopupAnimation_RunWorkerCompleted);
      _ThreadPopupAnimation.RunWorkerAsync(); 
// function continues to load form...
```

Except nothing happens. The code inside the thread is being called but not doing anything.
I tried using a spinner within the pop-up windows but that doesn't work until the form is already loaded.

Comment: What if you send the pop.Show() through the Dispatcher? UI code should run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have settled for a non threaded solution. The pop up shows static content warning the user it may be some time. Getting something to happen in the pop up window was beyond me!

```
  public FormView(String jSon, String jSonContent, String addressLine1, String postCode, String instanceId, int OwnerID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       BackgroundWorker _ThreadPopupAnimation = new BackgroundWorker();
       BusyPopupWindow pop = new BusyPopupWindow();

       pop.Show(); 

    // load form full of media content...
        var newFormCreator = new FormCreator(jSon, jSonContent, addressLine1, postCode, instanceId, OwnerID);
        newFormCreator.OnFormsUpdated += newFormCreator_OnFormsUpdated;
        mainContent.Content = newFormCreator;

        pop.Close();

    }
```